# Präposition in "auf eine Schule gehen"

Tags: usage, preposition

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Er hatte eine starke Legasthenie und sollte **auf eine Sonderschule gehen**. Seine Eltern schickten ihn stattdessen **auf eine Waldorfschule**.

Laut des [Reverso Wörterbuchs](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/schule) heißen die typischen Ausdrücke

> in die **or** zur Schule gehen

Es gibt zwar

> auf **or** in der Schule

aber die Bedeutung ist anders.

Gibt es spezifische Gründe, warum der Spiegel-Autor die Präposition "auf" in beiden Sätzen gewählt hat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- *In die / **zur** Schule* bezieht sich eher auf die tatsächliche Handlung:  Tasche packen und los...
- *In die / **auf die** Schule* bezieht sich auf die Zugehörigkeit zur Schule, welche Schule er regelmäßig besucht, wo er angemeldet ist.

Konstruiertes Beispiel (nicht besonders schön):

> Ich gehe auf die Karl-Maier-Schule, aber montags in der 6. Stunde gehen wir zur Helene-Müller-Schule zur Theater-AG.

Und natürlich hängt es vom Kontext ab, wie "in die" zu verstehen ist.

Comment: Bei mir haben sich zunächst die gleichen Assoziationen eingestellt. Dann ist mir aber aufgefallen, dass "in/zur" *doch* im nicht-konkreten Fall verwendet werden kann, wenn es nicht um eine bestimmte Schule geht: "Und, kleiner Mann, gehst Du schon in die/zur Schule?" Auf jeden Fall funktioniert "auf" in diesem Fall nicht. Kann man das vielleicht wie folgt zusammenfassen? "Auf" nur bei einer bestimmte Schule (Sonderschule, Realschule, Helene-Müller-Schule), "in die"/"zur", wenn es um Schule allgemein geht. Sicher bin ich mir aber noch nicht.

Comment: @Oguk "Gehst Du schon auf die Schule?" geht nicht? Hm. Ich hätte auch eher "zur" verwendet, aber "auf" löst auch keinen Krebs im Sprachzentrum meines Gehirns aus...

Comment: @Oguk: passt doch: der "kleine Mann" geht zur Schule ohne Berücksichtigung der konkreten Schule (das wäre ja "auf"), sondern der Sprecher bezieht sich auf die Handlung des Schulbesuchs - jetzt ist das Kind schon so groß, daß es zur Schule geht.

Comment: @Robert: "Auf" die Schule geht nur bei einer bestimmten Schule (die auch impliziert sein kann) oder einem Schultyp. Wenn hier(x) jemand sagt "auf die Grundschule", meint er damit die einzige Grundschule vor Ort. In der großen Nachbarstadt geht das Kind entweder zur Grundschule (weil es 6-10 Jahre alt ist), oder auf die XYZ-Grundschule.    (x)hier: SW-D. In anderen Regionen werden Präpositionen munter anders verwendet. (Wenn ich bedenke, wieviele Präpositionen die Arbeit oder ALDI haben kann.... "bei" ALDI gehen, sag' ich nur °_°)

Comment: @Stephie Genau, so denke ich auch, aber es mag natürlich regional unterschiedlich sein. Ich wollte mit meinem Kommentar auch nur darauf hinweisen, dass es mit "zur" nicht unbedingt um die konkrete Handlung "Tasche packen und los..." gehen muss (wie das Beispiel mit dem Kind zeigt). In der Antwort hört es sich so an, als würde "zur" nur bei der realen Tätigkeit verwendet ("Ich bin gerade auf dem Weg in die/zur Schule").

Answer (score 2):

In *Duden – Das Stilwörterbuch* werden die entsprechenden Formulierungen mit „in“ und „auf“ gleichwertig nebeneinander genannt:

> in/auf die höhere Schule gehen
>
> seine Kinder in/auf eine exklusive Schule schicken