# ''zur Schule'' vs ''in die Schule''

Tags: preposition

> - Ich gehe in die Schule.
> - Ich bringe meine Tochter zur Schule.

In my book, "in" is specified for places, while "zu" for activities and people.

But in the above sentence, zu was used for a place.
So I was wondering what is the difference between using in & zu in the above examples.

Comment: Your book is wrong. _Zu_ is used for places, too. For example: _zum Bahnhof_ → to the station, _zum Auto_ → to the car, _zu den Parkplätzen_ → to the parking lots. Furthermore, _in_ can also be used for persons: _Der Geist fuhr in mich hinein._ → The ghost went into me. The context determines which preposition is used.

Comment: related/may help: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/präposition-in-auf-eine-schule-gehen

Comment: Note *Schule* can be seen as a place, i.e. a building, and, in a more abstract sense, an *institution*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the school you are facing here is due to "going to school" being kind of a fixed expression. Both the sentence

> Ich gehe zur Schule.

and

> Ich gehe in die Schule.

Can mean

> I go to school.

as a general statement, you might even say such a sentence on a Sunday where there is no school.
If you want to get away from this sense of the sentence, there are differences though. In general, "in" is used as "into", where you actually enter something, while "zu" is used as "to", where you are going to some place (and maybe enter, who knows?). For example:

> Ich gehe zum Supermarkt.

In this sentence, you are saying that you are heading to the supermarket, and of course it is assumed that you actually enter and do some shopping there. On the other hand

> Ich gehe jetzt in den Supermarkt.

emphasizes the fact that you enter it, right this second. In general, "zu" is more common and "in" is only used when you really want to emphasize the "into".

And of course "in" and "zu" have lots of other meanings, that is only their use related to places. :)

Answer (score 0):

The exact meaning heavily depends on the region where the situation is set.

This is complicated by the fact that *Schule* is used in two different ways:

- the institution as a whole (i.e. all schools/any school)
- one building that houses a school

Interpretation for Austria:

> Ich gehe in die Schule

mostly means "I am attending school"

> Ich bringe meine Tochter in die (zur) Schule

means "I walk/drive her from home (or wherever we are) to the place/building"
 (I personally would not use *zur Schule*)

Comment: Also wenn Du sie nicht rein bringst, sondern nur an die Schule ran, würde ich eher "zur Schule" sagen.

Comment: @userunknown hängt sicher von Sprachumfeld/Alter ab.

Answer (score -1):

Prepositions can be tricky. **Zu** focuses on the journey instead of the destination.

> Ich gehe in die Schule.

I'm in front of the building and about to enter.

> Ich gehe zur Schule.

I'm far away from the school building and tell my destination to explain what I'm doing right now.

> Ich bringe meine Tochter in die Schule.

You *may* hear this in Austria, because they use the preposition *in* also for *the school as an institution*. So it's not about standing in front of the building and entering it – that would contradict the meaning of *bringen*. For my Northern German ears, it sounds wrong.

> Ich bringe meine Tochter zur Schule.

We are far away from the school building and I tell our destination to explain what we're doing right now.

Comment: Es ist viel komplizierter. Wenn man dem ersten Beispiel folgte, so müsste man sich bei _„Ich gehe in die Kästner-Grundschule“_ vorstellen, dass ich, vor der Kästner-Grundschule stehend, gleich das Gebäude betreten wollte. Das ist aber nicht gemeint.

Comment: Zudem kann ich als Urbrandenburger versichern, dass _jemanden in die Schule bringen_ auch im Norden vollkommen richtig klingt. Ich wage sogar zu behaupten, dass man es in der Umgangssprache dem Ausdruck _jemanden zur Schule bringen_ vorzieht.

Comment: Das ist wirklich regional sehr unterschiedlich. Ö:"gehst du schon in die Schule?" fragt, ob das Kind bereits eine Schule besucht.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: *Ich gehe **auf** die Kästner-Grundschule.* Wenn du es mit *in* sehr häufig hörst, ist es kein reiner Austriazismus. Vielleicht hat es sich über die DDR aus dem sächsischen auch im Nordosten eingeschlichen. Ich sitze hier im Harz genau an der Sprachgrenze zu einem gemischt-säggsschen Dialekt, da verstehe ich manche Ausdrücke auch nicht. Und umgekehrt.

Comment: @Janka Tatsächlich würde man da, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, sowas hören wie _Ick geh inne Kästna-Grundschule_. Der Ausdruck mit _auf_ kommt eher bei sächlichen Bezeichnungen vor: _Ick geh uffs Gauß(-Gymnasium)_.

Comment: M.E. kann man auch in 500m Entfernung, das Erreichen des Gebäudes antizipierend, sagen, dass man in die Schule geht. Ab 600m sollte man mit dem Rad fahren. Wenn man jetzt zur Schule geht, aber nicht hinein, weil vor der Schule der Bus für den Schulausflug wartet, sollte man nicht "in die Schule" sagen, weil es nicht stimmt. Die Institution könnte gemeint sein, wenn die Mutter ein 5jähriges Kind, das eigentlich noch 1 Jahr warten müsste, wegen großer Begabung schon mit 5 in die Schule bringen will - das wäre die Institution Schule. Am ersten Schultag bringt man das Kind in die Schule, dann zur.